# Pass Azure DevOps pipeline Variable to package.json file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, package.json, cypress

I want to connect azure pipeline to my app and run my tests in headless mode by using cypress, and I need to pass Azure DevOps variable (which is my cypress record key) to my package.json. How can I pass variable right way?

I try to create Azure variable, pass it in `.yml` and receive in `package.json`

here is my `.yml` script part:

```
    npm run test:e2e:headless:record $(RECORD_KEY)
  displayName: 'Run Cypress tests headless'
```

and here is my package.json script part:

`"test:e2e:headless:record": "vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless --record --key RECORD_KEY"`

my azure job failed in this line, which means my `package.json` don't receive `RECORD_KEY` variable:
`test:e2e:headless:record: vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless --record --key RECORD_KEY`

Comment: why is your yaml ***P***RECORD_KEY but your json RECORD_KEY?

Comment: oh sorry it's just a typo, they are the same in code

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Could you pass the variable to json file successfully now? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to pass the variable value to Package.json file?

In your package.json, write the variable with the format `@@RECORD_KEY@@`:

```
"test:e2e:headless:record": "vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless --record --key @@RECORD_KEY@@
```

This is the screenshot of my package.json file:

[image]

Then, in replace token task, configure the file path and file which will be replaced token:

[image]

[image]

Note, not forget to configure the value in Variable tab if the variable is not the pre-defined variable.

[image]

Then, execute the pipeline, in your local log, you will see that the value has been passed successfully:

[image]